# Adding a matrix to the first dimension of a 3D array

Tags: r

I am sorry if the title is not very accurate, I did not find a simple way to put it. I am having trouble with a seemingly simple operation in R.

Let's say I have a matrix A 2x2 (with elements Aij i=1,2 j=1,2), and I want to "transform" this matrix in a 3 dimensional array B 2x2x2 where: Bhij= Aij for h=1,2. 
I have the following code:

```
A=cbind(c(1,2), c(3,4))
B<-array(NA, dim=c(2,2,2)
for (h in 1:2){
   B[h,,]<-A
}
```

But I would want to do the same thing without using loop. Is there a way to do that?

Thank you very much,

Aurélien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple method that uses the column dominant storage system in R and `rep` is as follows:

```
B[] <- rep(A, each=2)
```

The `[]` force B to maintain its array structure, while, `rep` strips the dimensionality from A and returns a vector.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this works well if the first dimension has length 2. However if it is 3 or higher your solution does not work if I am correct.

Comment: I am sorry apparently I did something wrong the first time I tried with another dimension. I chose your answer for its simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

There's a package, abind, that contains a function of the same name that will do that for you in one step:

```
library(abind)
B <-abind(A,A, along=3)
B
#----------------
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this information, as I may have to combine matrices for dimensions other than the first one, this may be very helpful!